# socket.io is disconnecting all other connected users in my node twitter app

Tags: node.js, twitter, stream, socket.io

When I open two browser windows in incognito mode (different sessions).

I get a stream for one, which works fine...new tweets come in as expected from the twitter stream api. The problem is that when the other window loads the page, the first incognito window gets disconnected.

Here is the code I'm using. I'm not sure if twitter might not allow simultaneous streams or if its something with my logic.

```
var mod = module.exports = {}
    , twitter = require('twitter')
    , c = console;

var io
    , sock
    , intv = {};

function onNewsInit(data){
    setTimeout(function(){
        stream(streamQuery);
    }, 1000 * 5);
}

function stream(query){
    c.log('stream query', query);

    twit.stream('statuses/filter', {track:query}, function(stream) {
        stream.on('data', function (data) {
            c.log(data);
            var item = getItem(query, data);

            c.log('stream item', item);
            if ( item ) {
                sock.emit('twitter:item', { item: item });
            }

        });
        stream.on('end', function (response) {
            // Handle a disconnection
            c.log('stream end');
        });
        stream.on('destroy', function (response) {
            // Handle a 'silent' disconnection from Twitter, no end/error event fired
            c.log('stream destroy');
        });

        // Disconnect stream after five seconds
        sock.on('news:end', stream.destroy);
        sock.on('disconnect', stream.destroy);
    });
}


mod.register = function register(soc, sio) {
    c.log('news register');

    io = sio;
    sock = soc;

    sock.on('news:init', onNewsInit);
    sock.on('news:end', onNewsEnd);

};
```

app.js

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(sock){
    news.register(sock, io);
});
```

Is there any reason one client would be able to disconnect the other?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the twitter stream API only allows one simultaneous connection.

As described here:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/public

> Connections
>
> Each account may create only one standing connection to the public
>   endpoints, and connecting to a public stream more than once with the
>   same account credentials will cause the oldest connection to be
>   disconnected.
>
> Clients which make excessive connection attempts (both successful and
>   unsuccessful) run the risk of having their IP automatically banned.

Comment: But you can create as many apps as you want and make that one simultaneous connection from each of one of them. (if you have different projects or you want to classify the stream from the beginning. Like one app capture stream from tracking keywords and store it in DB and the other one tracks the locations and visualize it)